# Golang - how to define multiple projects in workspace

Tags: go

The GOPATH in Go points to the workspace. Can I create multiple projects in my workspace and have GOPATH point to a list of the locations of these projects?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28394596/6309

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have multiple projects in your workspace. However, you do not specify multiple `GOPATH`s for that. You simply create your two projects within that `GOPATH` environment. And to compile, run etc you simply specify the entry point you want to use.

E.g.

```
go run src/proj1/proj1.go
go run src/proj2/proj2.go
```

For more information on GOPATH and workspaces, see [the godoc on workspaces](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces).

Specifically, “src contains Go source files organized into packages (one package per directory),”. Notice that you are not limited to only one main package.

Comment: so it's workspace/src/(proj1src, proj2src etc), workspace/pkg/(proj1pkg, proj2pkg etc) and so on? Is there any way to do workspace/proj1/(src, pkg, bin)?

Comment: What do you do if you have two projects and they need to be in two different Github Repositories?  
Where do you init the git project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use single workspace but if you want to work with another project out of workspace, you should check your imports. Because when you import golang packages

```
import "fmt"
```

It searchs "fmt" package on GOROOT
or other packages which is get via

```
go get github.com/package
```

It puts package under `%workspace(GOPATH)%\src\github.com`. It doesn't put package under your project. So you can clone 3rd party projects under your project folder and set imports like relative path notation:

```
import "./github.com/package"
```

then run your go files. It works.