# Is it possible to develop Go on a project basis? (without a gopath)

Tags: go

Say I wanted to integrate a go project into another repo, or wanted to develop a temporary project on my desktop. My current understanding is that in order to develop anything, it must be within my gopath.

Is this unique to Go?
Is there a way to, for example, `go init` a folder and use that as a self contained project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I illustrated in [Automatically defining GOPATH on a per project basis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28394596/6309), it depends on your IDE.

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) will detect automatically a Go project structure (`myProject/src`) and set a `GOPATH` just for that project.

See "[GOPATH in the VS Code Go extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension)"

You would find the same feature in GoLand, the IntelliJ editor (not free).
See [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/7iro00/using_goland_fairly_new_to_go_where_do_i_set_the/).

> - **Global GOPATH**: this allows you to configure a GOPATH (which can have multiple values, of course) for all the projects you are using the IDE with. You'll configure it once and reuse it across the projects
> - **Project GOPATH**: has the same properties as the Global GOPATH but this one applies only to the current project. This means you can configure different GOPATH values for different projects.