# how can I add ./bin as first element to the path while using rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I want ./bin as first element in my PATH variable.
I have this is my bashrc.

```
export PATH=./bin:~/bin:$PATH
```

However the PATH is prepended with the bin of the current gemset by RVM... So rvm is prepending my path. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It's not a very elegant solution, but this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360738/execute-a-bash-function-upon-entering-a-directory asks about calling a bash function every time you cd into *any* directory.  You could have a bash function which moves `./bin` to the start of PATH, if it's not at the start already.  Although it would be interesting to see if this gets called before or after rvm does its magic: if it gets called before then it probably wouldn't work.

Comment: Since my dotfiles were very well organized I needed to but the PATH setup after invoking the rvm utility scripts... So finally I found the solution.

Comment: Ah cool.  It's worth answering your own question in case anyone else has the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Finally since my dotfiles were very well organized I need to put the PATH prepend right after invoking the rvm utility scripts:

```
# ----------------------------------- RVM -----------------------------------
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
[[ -r $rvm_path/scripts/completion ]] && . $rvm_path/scripts/completion
export PATH=./bin:$PATH
```