# How to save the bash history of $PWD into $PWD/.history

Tags: bash

I'm working on an open source project to tracking the research activities. In one of the modules, I want to track the command history of a folder into the file(`.history`) which is the same folder.

**Example**:

Let's say, I'm working on a folder `/Users/ravi/test-project/` .
I'm using few of commands to start my work in that folder. Let's say I executed the following commands in the folder.

```
$wget https://mywebsite.com/script.py
$chmod +xw script.py
$echo "append some text " >  script.py 
$python script.py
```

I want all these commands to be saved into .history file of the folder ie., `/Users/ravi/test-project/.history`.

Help much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360738/execute-a-bash-function-upon-entering-a-directory for how to execute a command whenever you change directories. You can use this to change `$HISTFILE`.

Comment: On Changing directory method looks interesting, my only concern is whether that will work if a user does "open terminal here" from the right click menu. I will dig deep into it thanks.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work. It runs the function every time it displays a shell prompt.

Comment: Also regarding `$HISTFILE`. I tried `export HISTFILE=$PWD/.bash_history` in the folder. but its not creating the file .bash_history or saving the history.  Any thoughts @Barmar

Comment: By default it doesn't save history until the shell exits. At that time it will use the current value of `HISTFILE`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/67283/is-it-possible-to-make-writing-to-bash-history-immediate for how to make it save after every command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually pretty easy:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; HISTFILE=\${PWD}/.history"
```

This first ensures that [history is written and then re-read on every prompt](https://askubuntu.com/a/115625/10371)*. Then it changes the history file variable to use the current directory. Example session:

```
$ echo "$PWD"
/home/username
$ cd /tmp
$ echo "$PWD"
/tmp
$ cat ~/.history 
echo "$PWD"
cd /tmp
$ cat .history
echo "$PWD"
```

As you can see, the `cd` command is stored in the history file of the directory the command was executed in, and the `echo` commands are stored in both history files.

One side effect to note is that history is now shared between every terminal. I love this feature, but not everyone does.

Also, if you're looking for **auditing** rather than convenience of history you should probably look into enabling auditd or something similar.

* Don't worry, it's super fast even with [thousands of lines of history](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/c0e34f86b3893e0815fea4afe3af7f545228d4ee/.bash_history).

Comment: This is what I needed :D, I owe you a beer  . Cheers . Thanks for good explanation .

Comment: If I ever visit Hyderabad, sure! Good luck with the project!

Comment: Sure.. Thanks again :D